# Перевести первичный балл в тестовый балл с помощью Excel?

Tags: excel

Есть таблица соответствия первичных и тестовых баллов:

[image]

Как с помощью формулы задать поиск соответствующего тестового балла для ячейки E2?

[image]

т.е. в нашем случае ответом станет 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте о функции *ВПР()*